# I'm very beginner and I try to mock or simulate params inside grails tagLib using MockFor?

Tags: unit-testing, grails, testing

**Example TagLib:** 
   I need to mock the 'params' to be used in some request

```
class MyTagLib {
   static namespace = 'p'

   format = { attrs -->
      def siteId = params.siteId // I need to mock this 
      def domainLanguage = params.domainLanguage.toString()
      .
      .
      . 
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should start by looking at http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/testing.html#unitTestingTagLibraries

And in your case you can probably do something like:

```
@TestFor(MyTagLib)
class MyTagLibSpec extends Specification {
    def "test something with params"() {
       given:
       params.siteId == "mySiteId"
       params.domainLanguage = new DomainLanguage()

       when:
       def result = tagLib.format(attr1: 'someAtribute').toString()

       then:
       result == 'expectedOutput'  
    }
}
```

But I would definetly try and read the documentation first :-)

Comment: Thank you so much, was helpful